# Creating simple "Greater Than" filter on a Tableau Measure

Tags: filter, tableau-api, dashboard

I'm creating a simple filter on a tableau measure field to only show impressions over 50. I created a calculated field to do this and noticed that the impression sums have changed causing a (very small) false discrepancy. How do I create a filter that doesn't effect overall sum of values?

For example, without the filter my total is 380,052 impressions but with the filter I have 379,923.

I've tried adding the "Impressions" measure to the "Filters" and adjusting the filter to show 50 or more impressions. I've also tried creating a simple IF statement, such as, sum(if [IMPRESSIONS] > 50 then [IMPRESSIONS] END)

Neither work but I need to create a filter to only include impressions over 50...any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an example with sample data and screenshots?

Comment: can you uncheck `Aggregate Measures` and check

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are trying to do. Normally when you filter the data in a view, you want the view to show the result of applying the filter (otherwise why filter?). If you are looking at multiple results some of which you don't want to filter then you probably want to use level detail calculations that exclude the filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem can be solved using set. If that does not work then please share sample data to help you out.

Comment: I don't think sets work on measures, only for dimensions.